# AirConsole: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: airconsole

I keep getting the error in the title when I try to run the game. I've been trying to get the "Getting Started" scripts going that just show some text but this has been blocking me.

This is the full error:

```
airconsole-unity-plugin.js:194 
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:7843/api' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Since I'm new to AirConsole, and fairly new to Javascript I'm not quite sure what to do. I've tried restarting my pc which fixed it for a second but then it didn't show the text it was supposed to.
I've also tried changing the ports of the server settings for AirConsole but this doesn't solve it either.

EDIT: FOLLOW-UP.
I've noticed that this error only happens when I'm debugging the game (F5 in Visual Studio).

Comment: Do you have some firewalls activated? Which OS?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. Apparently when I disable Windows Firewall completely it seems to work. I don't seem to receive/send the messages that the controller should send now though. (the ones from the Getting Started guide)

Comment: @AndrinvonRechenberg I've been trying some more. I've got it to work completely except for the connection refused once in a while. The firewall still seems to be a problem I guess but I'm not sure how to solve it. It only happens sometimes so it's fine for now!

Answer (score 0):

According to the our conversation in the comments of the question, the problem was a local firewall.

If other people also experience the same problem, disable your firewall to test it.